# How to calculate some specific data function from the data of a large CSV file

Tags: java, csv, for-loop, arraylist, collections

I'm trying to work out the most expensive county to rent a building from data in a CSV file. The data from each column I need the data from has been put into a list. The price range is set by the user so the outer most for loop and if statement ensure that the buildings considered are in the set price range.

The price of a building is also slightly complicated because the price is the minimum stay x price.

In the code below I am trying to get the average property value of one county just son I can get the basic structure right before I carry on, but I'm kind of lost at this point any help would be much appreciated.

```
public int sampleMethod()
    {
        ArrayList<String> county = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<Integer> costOfBuildings = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        ArrayList<Integer> minimumStay = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        ArrayList<Integer> minimumBuildingCost = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        try{
            //Code to read data from the CSV and put the data in the lists.
            }
        }
        catch(IOException | URISyntaxException e){
            //Some code.
        }
       
        int count = 0;
        int avgCountyPrice = 0;
        int countyCount = 0;
        for (int cost : costOfBuildings) {
            if (costOfBuildings.get(count) >= controller.getMin() && costOfBuildings.get(count) <= controller.getMax()) {
                for (String currentCounty: county) {
                    for (int currentMinimumStay: minimumStay) {
                        if (currentCounty.equals("sample county")) {
                            countyCount++;
                            int temp = nightsPermitted * cost;
                            avgCountyPrice = avgCountyPrice + temp / countyCount;
                        }
                    } 
                }
            } 
            count++;
        }
        return avgCountyPrice ;   
    }
```

Here is a sample table to depict what the CSV looks like, also the CSV file has more than 50,000 rows.

| name | county | price | minStay |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Morgan | lydney | 135 | 5 |
| John | sedury | 34 | 1 |
| Patrick | newport | 9901 | 7 |

Comment: Is each arraylist representing a separate column in the CSV file?  Have you considered implementing an object representing a row in the file?  This could facilitate calculation of the stats for multiple counties.  Existing implementation seems to calculate something for just one county.  It would be better to provide a short sample file and expected output of the calculation.

Comment: Your are correct in that each arraylist represents one column in the CSV file. I don't know how t extract the specific information that I would need. Also, There are 53,000+ rows.

Answer (score 0):

Let’s describe the algorithm of your task: Group the CSV file by county, calculate the average price in each group, and find the country that has the highest average price for buildings. The code will be rather long if you try to finish the task using Java. It is convenient and simple to get this done in SPL, the open-source Java package. The language only needs one line of code:

|  | A |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | =file("data.csv").import@ct().groups(county;avg(price):price_avg).top(-1;price_avg).county |

SPL offers JDBC driver to be invoked by Java. Just store the above SPL script as mostExpensiveCounty.splx and invoke it in Java in the same way you call a stored procedure:

```
…
Class.forName("com.esproc.jdbc.InternalDriver");
con= DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:esproc:local://");
st = con.prepareCall("call mostExpensiveCounty()");
st.execute();
…
```